# ansible: if variable is undefined use default

Tags: ansible

I have simple line in ansible as following

```
"{{ var1 | join(',') | default('{{ var2.stdout }}') }}"
```

when I define var1 playbook works fine, but when I don't define var1 I get error var1 is undefined. I want to make sure if the var1 is undefine use the default. how can I achieve that without when conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You will always get an error here when `var1` is not defined. The `join` filter is expecting a value which produces the error.

The default filter needs to be applied directly on the var. It would be easier if your default value could be joined as well in this case. Passing default as a single element list might do the trick

```
"{{ var1 | default([var2.stdout]) | join(',') }}"
```

Note: see correction above. The call to `default` is already in a jinja2 template expression. So the var passed as param must not be a block itself.

Comment: every character in default value gets join by ,

Comment: Did you add the list markers arround the var name ? => `[...]`. With this it shouldn't

Answer (score -3):

```
{% if var1 is undefined %}{{ … }}{{% endif %}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24588502)

Comment: It should be more than enough for him as it solves all exactly his issue.